# Pass XSLT element to C# code

Tags: c#, xml, xslt, xpathnodeiterator

In my XML, I have something like this:

```
<people>
    <person>
        <name>
            <first>Bob</first>
            <last>Bobbertson</last>
        </name>
        <age>80</age>
    </person>
    ...
</people>
```

I want to be able to pass the entire `<person>` section to my code-behind so that in my C# code, I can have access to all of the subnodes (`<name>`, `<first>`, `<last>`).

I am using XSLT to generate my HTML, and in my XSLTfile, I have a line like this:

```
<xsl:value-of select="custom:SelectPerson($selectedPerson)"/>
```

Which calls this in my code-behind:

```
public string SelectPerson(System.Xml.XPath.XPathNodeIterator selectedPersonNodes)
{
    foreach (var node in selectedPersonNodes)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(node.ToString());
    }
    ...
}
```

What I want to happen is to have the `foreach` loop three times, and print out "Bob", then "Bobbertson", then "80". But what is happening is that it goes through once and prints out "BobBobbertson80".

Is there a way to pass the nodes in the way I want from the XSLT-generated HTML to my code-behind?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't shown us how `$selectedPerson` is defined, but I would suggest trying this to pass a set of the individual nodes to the function:

```
<xsl:value-of
     select="custom:SelectPerson($selectedPerson//*[not(*)])"/>
```

Comment: I didn't know you could do this. Thank you, this solved my problem!

Answer (score 2):

Note that the C# code below is ***untested*** as I don't have access to a C# development environment.

What your C# code is doing is correct. You are passing an iterator that contains just one node. (Examine `selectedPersonNodes.Count` to check). That node is the element `<person>` which, as you say, has descendants, but it is still a single node.

Assuming your `XPathNodeIterator` can ever contain multiple `person` elements, you should write

```
foreach (var person in selectedPersonNodes)
{
  Debug.WriteLine(person.SelectSingleNode("name/first").ToString());
  Debug.WriteLine(person.SelectSingleNode("name/last").ToString());
  Debug.WriteLine(person.SelectSingleNode("age").ToString());
}
```

or if it always contains a *single* person, you can say

```
selectedPersonNodes.MoveNext();
XPathNavigator person = selectedPersonNodes.Current;

Debug.WriteLine(person.SelectSingleNode("name/first").ToString());
Debug.WriteLine(person.SelectSingleNode("name/last").ToString());
Debug.WriteLine(person.SelectSingleNode("age").ToString());
```

but, as I said, you may want to check the value of `selectedPersonNodes.Count` before you do either of these.